# Take next pushed value and await - Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I have a observable of "hot" payloads:

```
IObservable<Payload> Payloads;
```

I have a setup function where I now need to grab a payload, to see what data is being passed through, before continuing with the Setup.

Conceptually, what I want to do is this :

```
Payload payload = await Payloads.First()
```

i.e. at that line of code I want to wait until a payload is available and then carry on.

Can I do that with anything already in Reactive Extensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do either:

```
await Payloads.Take(1);
```

or:

```
await Payloads.FirstAsync();
```